# Problems using Expert Fonts

Tags: fonts, lyx, fontspec

I recently purchased an expert font, Calluna (exljbris). There is only one problem when using the font:

The font is encoded with Old Style numbers by default. I don't know how to access the Lining Numbers.

I've tried using `Use Old Style Figures` thinking the font encoding was switched, but alas, it doesn't work; it stays in Old Style. I have also tried `\fontspec[Numbers={Lining}]{Calluna}` in the preamble and that hasn't worked.

I use LyX 2.1.0; Windows 8.1; I use XeTeX and `\fontspec` package.

The Lining Numbers exist in the encoding; it is on the foundry's website, and I also tested it with Microsoft Office 2013 which has the option available.

My LaTeX preamble looks like:

```
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
%\raggedbottom
%\usepackage{dtklogos}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Historic,Rare,Discretionary,TeX},Contextuals=Swash]{Calluna}
%\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage{microtype}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Please complete your code to make a complete, small compilable document so that others can reproduce the problem easily. (I can't as I don't have the font but hopefully others will.) I don't know much about Windows but on OS X, you can use `otfinfo -f` to get a list of the features provided by the font (in case it is using some non-standard name). [Also on GNU/Linux etc. but they don't have Word so I guess you are on Win or Mac.]

Comment: I have Calluna and, with both `xetex` and `luatex`, I get lining numbers when adding `Numbers={Lining}` to `\setmainfont[Ligatures={Historic,Rare,Discretionary,TeX},Contextuals=Swash]{Calluna}`.  Please add a complete document illustrating the problem, and details about the version of Calluna that you have.

Comment: I used the above suggestion of putting `Numbers={Lining}` into the font specification, and it worked.

Comment: As for @cfr , If the question wasn't answered so quickly, I would upload a small file or example. I will definitely do that next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without a minimal working example, this answer must be an untested guess, but the problem seems to be that you tried `\fontspec[Numbers={Lining}]{Calluna}` in the preamble instead of

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=Lining]{Calluna}
```

`\fontspec[Numbers={Lining}]{Calluna}` would be appropriate for one-time use.  E.g., if for some reason you wanted Calluna with lining numbers only in one quote, you could write

```
\begin{quote}
\fontspec[Numbers={Lining}]{Calluna}
12345
\end{quote}
```

That’s very far from being the most efficient way to change font, but it does work.  In the preamble, however, you want `\setmainfont` with its arguments.

By the way, `Ligatures=Rare` and `Ligatures=Discretionary` are two ways of saying the same thing, so choose one.  And Calluna does not have the `hlig` or `cswh` features, so remove `Ligatures=Historic` and `Contextuals=Swash`, otherwise your log file will fill up with distracting warnings. You could add `Contextuals=Alternate`, but `calt` should be on by default in `xetex`.

If you have both the serif and the sans, I would suggest using the font this way:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Contextuals=Alternate,Ligatures={TeX,Rare},Numbers=Lining,SmallCapsFeatures={Kerning=Uppercase}}
\setmainfont{Calluna}
\setsansfont{Calluna Sans}
```

Even better, since the rare ligatures suggest a typographic tradition in which lining figures were not the default, I’d either use the old-style figures, or omit the rare ligatures.

Comment: Yes, inefficiency is a problem with my LaTeX preamble. I have set `\defaultfontfeatures` to what you have described. I apologize; I'm slowly integrating into exclusive LaTeX.

The latter half of the answer is what worked; I tried using:

    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Numbers=Lining]{Calluna}

Comment: I just realized same person was issuing the answer.

Comment: I just noticed, when using the above settings, in LyX, the double quotes get all messed up. The standard curly quotes do not work anymore. When I use my example, but just add `Numbers=Lining` It produces ```` and `"` respectively in the output. The only time I can get curly quotes is to use my example, but just insert `Numbers=Lining`, but I want to get standard Ligatures. Should I open a new case?

Comment: No, just add `Ligatures=TeX` to `\defaultfontfeatures{}`. You used it in your question; sorry, I forgot to include it in my answer, because I always type the curly quotes directly.  Will fix my answer.